# Javascript new date treats differently towards different date style?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I tested the following code in firefox scratchpad and got interesting result?

```
var date=new Date("2012-05-12");
var date2 = new Date("05/12/2012");
date;
/*
Fri May 11 2012 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
*/
date2;
/*
Sat May 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
*/
```

Two dates are different. Apparently this is due to the timezone issue. What I want is date2 result. How can I make js engine correctly treats the ISO date style?

Comment: Remove the leading zero in the first example. `var date=new Date("2012-5-12");`

Comment: @j08691 that results in an "Invalid date" error, at least in Firefox.

Comment: @Pointy - Good catch, I tested in Chrome.

Comment: in IE8 i got:
LOG: NaN
LOG: Sat May 12 00:00:00 UTC-0300 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the string "2012-05-12" is taken to be an ISO 8601 date, while "05/12/2012" is an RFC 2822 date.  In the ISO format, the lack of a timezone implies UTC.  At midnight on the morning off May 12, in California (or wherever you are) it's 7 PM the previous evening.

The RFC date without a time zone, however, is parsed under the assumption that you want the timestamp for midnight in your **local** timezone. (Well, not necessarily *your* timezone; the timezone of the computer where your JavaScript runs :-)

You can see the difference if you pass those strings to `Date.parse()`.

The RFC date format can include an explicit time zone, but the ISO format cannot. (Well, it can, but browsers don't pay attention, and apparently IE doesn't handle those at all.)

*edit* — here's a simple (dumb; no error checking) function that'll give you a date from that 3-part ISO form:

```
function isoDate( str ) {
  var rv = null;
  str.replace(/^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/, function(_, yr, mn, dy) {
    rv = new Date(parseInt(yr, 10), parseInt(mn, 10) - 1, parseInt(dy, 10));
  });
  return rv;
}
```

Comment: Yeah what you answer is actually what I'm thinking. But any solutions...?

Comment: @NSF well you could parse the ISO date format yourself, and then construct the date explicitly.  If you construct a date with numeric, it should assume the local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

By the standard, with `Date()`, you can parse ISO dates or dates in an implementation-dependent format, in an an implementation-dependent manner. To get anything more reliable, use a suitable library that can parse dates in some known formats.